OpenWRT wpa_supplicant does not support the network block?
When I run the following conf (all boiler plate),
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=0
fast_reauth=1
network={
        ca_cert="/etc/config/auth/CA_XXXX.pem"
        client_cert="/etc/config/auth/Client_XXXX.pem"
        eap=TLS
        eapol_flags=0
        identity="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" # Internet (ONT) interface MAC address must match this value
        key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
        phase1="allow_canned_success=1"
        private_key="/etc/config/auth/PrivateKey_XXXX.pem"
}

I get the following error,
root@router:/etc/config# /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -D wired -i "10g-2" -dd -c /tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf  
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Line 5: unknown network field 'ca_cert'.
Line 6: unknown network field 'client_cert'.
Line 7: unknown network field 'eap'.
Line 8: unknown network field 'eapol_flags'.
Line 9: unknown network field 'identity'.
Line 11: unknown network field 'phase1'.
Line 12: unknown network field 'private_key'.
Line 13: failed to parse network block.
Failed to read or parse configuration '/tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf'.
: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all

Note running the same file outside of OpenWRT works fine, tested on Debian with wpa_supplicant v2.10. But on the version of wpa_supplicant (v2.11-devel) which ships with OpenWRT, 23.05.2 I get a failure. Why doesn't the OpenWRT version of wpa_supplicant support the network block, and how can I resolve this problem?

wpad-basic (the default) to blame
I had wpad-basic which doesn't support EAP.

wpad-basic - 2023-09-08-e5ccbfc6-6 - This package contains a basic IEEE 802.1x/WPA Authenticator and Supplicant with WPA-PSK, 802.11r and 802.11w support.

I solved it by switching it out with wpad-wolfssl
# opkg remove wpad-basic-mbedtls
Removing package wpad-basic-mbedtls from root...
# opkg install wpad-wolfssl

Update: I found out wpad-wolfssl wouldn't work either and had to move to wpad-openssl
